# Futures that flatMap a list of futures are doing a blocking operation, so why not enclose the code in blocking {..}?

Tags: multithreading, scala, future, blocking

In working through some of the exercises and videos from the Coursera class on [Reactive Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive) I saw this definition of a method to 'sequence' a `List` of futures.  The method returns a `Future` which will do the work of waiting on all the futures in `fts` (see code below) and packaging those results in a `List[T]` that will be available when the `Future[List[T]]` returned by sequence is complete.

```
def sequence[T](fts: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = {
    fts match {
        case Nil => Future(Nil)
        case (ft::fts) => ft.flatMap(t => sequence(fts)
            .flatMap(ts => Future(t::ts)))
    }
}
```

This code was given by the instructor, so I'm guessing that it should represent the optimal pattern for how to do this kind of thing.  However, elsewhere in the lectures the instructors state:

> Whenever you have a long-running computation or blocking make sure to
>   run it inside the blocking construct. For example:
>
> ```
>     blocking {
>       Thread.sleep(1000)
>     }
> ```
>
> is used to designate a piece of code as potentially blocking. An asynchronous computation that has a blocking construct is
>   typically scheduled in a separate thread to avoid potential deadlock.
>   Example: let's say you have a future f that waits on a timer or for a
>   resource or a monitor condition that can only be fulfilled by some
>   other future g. In that case, the part of the code in f that does the
>   waiting should be wrapped in the blocking, otherwise the future g
>   might never be run.

Now... what I don't understand is why the 'match' expression was not wrapped in a 'blocking' expression.  Don't we expect all the flatMapping to take (potentially) a noticeable chunk of time ?

Side Note: There is an 'official' sequence method  in the scala.concurrent.Future class and that implementation also does not use blocking.

I will also post this to the Coursera forums and if I get an answer back, I will post here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't we expect all the flatMapping to take (potentially) a noticeable chunk of time?

Nope. `flatMap` just constructs a new `Future` and returns immediately. It doesn't block.

See [the default implementation of `flatMap`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/549dc880c5525e3a2f3ea6af35c7ae8a349b2bdc/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L246). Here's a simplified version of it:

```
trait Future[+T] {

  def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])
                (implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {

    val promise = new Promise[S]()

    this.onComplete {

      // The first Future (this) failed
      case Failure(t) => promise.failure(t)

      case Success(v1) =>

        // Apply the flatMap function (f) to the first Future's result
        Try(f(v1)) match {

          // The flatMap function (f) threw an exception
          case Failure(t) => promise.failure(t)

          case Success(future2) =>
            future2.onComplete {

              // The second Future failed
              case Failure(t) => promise.failure(t)

              // Both futures succeeded - Complete the promise
              // successfully with the second Future's result.
              case Success(v2) => promise.success(v2)
            }
        }
    }
    promise.future
  }
}
```

Overview of what happens when you call `flatMap`:

1. Create a promise
2. Add a callback to this future
3. Return the promise

> The method returns a `Future` which will do the work of waiting on all the futures

I think that description is somewhat misleading. The `Future` that you get back from `Future.sequence` doesn't really "do work". As you can see in the code above, the `Future` you get from `flatMap` (and thus the `Future` you get from `Future.sequence`) is just a promise that will eventually be completed by something else. The only thing that ever really does anything is the `ExecutionContext`; the `Future`s just specify what to do.